# Different ways to ring a bell in Aaradhanam

Tags: worship, rituals, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

When performing *Aradhanam*, a daily *Pooja* performed by *Sri Vaishnavites*, there are certain moments when one is supposed to ring a *Ghantam*, or bell. The bell produces an auspicious sound synonymous with "Om", which is why it is used. However, there are two ways to ring the bell depending on the circumstances.

> There are two ways you can make sound with ghaNTa (Bell). One ringing
>   it such a way that the tongue touches  only one side of the ghaNTa.
>   You have to make ghaNTa naatham like this while
>
> - Opening the koyil aazhvar( the Divine box where PerumaL is in yoga
>     nidra)
> - While offering argyam, paadyam, and aachamaniiyam
> - While doing
>     thirumanjanam
> - While offering Dhupam, Diipam
>
> The tongue of the ghaNTa should touch both the sides of the bell while
>   doing Harati and while offering food.

([Source](http://srivaishnavam.com/aradhana.htm))

What is the reason for this difference in how the bell is rung? If the sound of the bell is auspicious, why not just ring it in the full manner all the time?

Comment: Is this a practice specific to Sri Vaishnavas, or is it a general practice of pujas done by all sects?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan To be honest I am not completely sure. I personally am Vaishnavite and have not even witnessed poojas for other sects except ISKCON. However, the source (not including my father) is from SriVaishnava.com so I have a hunch it is a Vaishnavite practice.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Also, it is particular to Aradhanam, and I do not believe that other sects practice that specific type of pooja.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a Sri Vaishnava as well, so I don't have much experience with poojas of other sects either.

Comment: the reason for difference in ringing of the bell could be: during aarti or while offering the time is doubly auspicious, as opposed to other regular times. Therefore why not resound the bell of Joy twice and rejoice-doubly blessed :)

Comment: There is difference in ringing the bell because it is like a wakeup call or calling the lord. When we call a person who is sleeping,we call him in one way. When he is beside us, we call him other way. When we pacify some child, we talk to him another way. While singing a lullaby, it differs. It applies to the lord also. That is why we ring the bell differently in different occasions.